# QJsonDocument::fromVariant() not able to encode QPoint?

Tags: qt5

I'd like to save a QVariantMap as JSON using built-in Qt 5.2.0 functionality (Windows7, Qt5.2.0, MinGW4.8). QJsonDocument seems not to be able to handle QPoint types, although they are encoded as QVariant successfully. Here an example:

```
int main()
{
    QPoint point(23, 42);

    QVariantMap settings;
    settings["point"] = point;
    qDebug() << settings;

    QJsonDocument json;
    json = QJsonDocument::fromVariant(settings);

    qDebug() << json;
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
QMap(("point", QVariant(QPoint, QPoint(23,42) ) ) )  
QJsonDocument({"point": null})
```

Why is `point` in `json` `null`? What are the limitations to JSON encoding regarding built-in datatypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't serialize any data type directly to JSON. You'll need to do some manual work.

For example, to serialize you could do something as simple as converting to a `QString` with a custom notation:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QVariantMap>
#include <QPoint>
#include <QPointF>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Q_UNUSED(argc)
    Q_UNUSED(argv)

    QPoint point(23, 42);
    //QPointF point(3234.23, 3423.22);
    //QString point = "sdfsdf";

    QVariantMap settings;
    settings["point"] = QString("(%1, %2)").arg(point.x()).arg(point.y());

    QJsonObject jsonobj = QJsonObject::fromVariantMap(settings);
    QJsonDocument json = QJsonDocument(jsonobj);


    qDebug() << settings;
    qDebug() << jsonobj.toVariantMap();
    qDebug() << json;
}
```

Example results:

```
QMap(("point", QVariant(QString, "(23, 42)") ) )  
QMap(("point", QVariant(QString, "(23, 42)") ) )  
QJsonDocument({"point": "(23, 42)"})
```

To deserialize you'll need to fiddle a little more, but should be equally easy.

From [JSON Support in Qt](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-nosubdir/json.html):

```
JSON is a format to store structured data. It has 6 basic data types:

* bool
* double
* string
* array
* object
* null
```

Comment: My original intent was to serialize data structures in a human readable format. The "human readable" part is not so important that it is worth the manual work. I'll go with http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/datastreamformat.html for my use case. Thanks for explaining!